# Logistic regression in r for aggregated counts

Tags: regression, logistic

I have country level data for a binary (good/bad) outcome. For each country, I have the number of individuals in the sample who answerd "good" and number of individuals who answered "bad". I also have percent of the sample (instead of number). So basically, instead of 1/0 for outcome, for each obseration (country) I have % of people for each category of the binary outcome. Hope this is clear enough...

How can I create a logistic regression model in R for this?

Comment: Glm package : For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) or as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures.

Comment: This looks like it's asking for R code but it seems it's actually a stats question in disguise.

Comment: The answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55916/generalized-lm-or-lm-in-ecological-dataset/55919#55919) describes three approaches (all of which are implemented in R).

Comment: @John, what stats question are you seeing?

Comment: @gung, the actual model to use is probably not simple logistic regression, perhaps multi-level logistic or weighted beta. I happily concede it's written as an R question.

Comment: That's a reasonable point. Jenny, in light of @John's comment, can you provide more information about your situation, your data & your goals? It may be that this is an on-topic Q & that we can point you towards the most appropriate methods for your case.

Answer (score 6):

Try reading the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html).  It states:

> A typical predictor has the form response ~ terms where response is the (numeric) response vector and terms is a series of terms which specifies a linear predictor for response. **For binomial** and quasibinomial families **the response can also be specified as** a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) or as **a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures**.

You can find an example in King's R logistic regression tutorial [here](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/logistic.html) under **Logistic Regression: One Numerical Predictor**.